# Apache Cassandra 2.1.17 storage path

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Are installing a new cassandra 2.1.17 cluster and when I create my app KS I see paths created like:

```
<data directory>/<KS>/<CF>-<some-large-key>
```

With some-large-key like:

```
8feb16f00fb711e7a670c3184f09fbe0
7588a2500fb711e7a670c3184f09fbe0
```

eta. Our current 2.1.15 clusters (w/KS created under v.2.0.x) uses though just:

```
<data directory>/<KS>/<CF>
```

Wondering about why the difference?

Answer (score 1):

This is from version 3 documentation, but the principle applies to 2.1 also (can't really get to google stored version of 2.1. because datastax set a robots file):

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html

Let's break it down:

```
/data/data/ks1/cf1-5be396077b811e3a3ab9dc4b9ac088d/la-1-big-Data.db
```

represents a data file.

ks1 represents the keyspace name to distinguish the keyspace for streaming or bulk loading data.

A hexadecimal string, 5be396077b811e3a3ab9dc4b9ac088d in this example, is appended to table names to represent unique table IDs.

why the unique table ids?

Well when there are updates to schema of a table (column family), the nodes first have to agree on the schema of a new tables, they are using this uuid to know in which version of schema tables are stored. You can cross check the uuids that are in cf's names with following query:

```
select keyspace_name, table_name, id from system_schema.tables;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!